# Iframe cookies problem due to new ITP policy

Tags: c#, cookies, safari, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization

I'm working in a web app which is in iframe inside foreign domain. That is, a customer web page with domain (let's say) "customer.com" has an iframe targeting our domain (let's say) "provider.com".

In almost every web browser it seems to work right, but we have a problem in Safari and Brave because this web browsers avoid third-party cookies due to ITP. But our ASP.Net MVC web app nees ASPXAUTH cookie in order to work.

I've spent a lot of hours tryint to understand how can I get rid of ASPXAUTH cookie, and finally I understand that maybe implementing any sort of token-based authorization can be the solution.
But the thing that I don't understand is how  I can make work the application using this authorization without using cookies (using local/session storage) and append implicity the authorization header in every request to server because it sounds so crazy to change every request in our web app to add this new header.

It's there any way to add this header "automatically" like cookies do?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You may need to include some sample lines of code to let ppl know how your web works currently. Eg: if you use lib X to send request, someone will point out how to set a hook on lib X to include a header on every request without rewrite all of your code

Comment: Thanks @HùngPhạmViệt, we're using ASP.Net MVC 5, requests to server side are done vía http forms and vanilla javascript. We do not use any third-party library to run requests against server side. So that's the point I don't add more info in my OP in order to focus in what I think it's important.